# is there any existing ant buildfile (build.xml) browser?

Tags: ant, build, explorer, build.xml

The question says it all. I am looking for a `build.xml` file browser where I can just jump from target to target easily. A tree for targets would be great. I am not sure if such things exist yet.

Google search doesn't help. So I ask my fellow SO mates. Do you know of any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse provide excellent Ant support, including build file outline views.

- [Ant and Maven Integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ant_maven.html) (see second half)
- [Eclipse Ant Editor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-anteditor.htm)